# Preventing a form submission with jquery ujs if the field is empty

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that submits with data-remote => true.

The form has one field, a textarea. I want to prevent submission of the form if the textarea length is 0 and only allow a form submission if the length is GT 1.

How do I bind to the form in a rails 3, jquery ujs friendly way. I tried the following but that did not stop the form submissions:

```
 $('#new_feedback').bind('ajax:before', function() {
      e.preventDefault();
 } );
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about what you want to do, but it seems that your anonymous function is missing a `e` parameter :  `$('#new_feedback').bind('ajax:before', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
 } );`

Answer (score 8):

You can bind directly to the form itself.  This way, you can check the field you want as well as any other fields you may want to check when the form is submitted.  return false is what cancels the form submission.

```
$('#myform').submit(function()
{
   if($('#fieldtocheck').val().length < 1)
   {
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: @downvoter Care to comment?  I realize this answer is nearly 2 years old and the internals of jQuery have changed slightly, but this is still a valid answer.